# Euclidean distance units for WGS84 files?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, epsg

I have a lake raster file and I want to calculate the euclidean distance. My raster file is in `EPSG 4326` and I use the `r.grow.distance` from GRASS GIS through QGIS plugins. What are the units from the `r.grow.distance` for a file with `EPSG 4326` and how can I transform the distance to meters? The area is between 50N to 60N.

Comment: The result is degrees, and you can't. I suggest you reproject your data to a fitting local UTM strip.

Comment: @Erik, thank you for your response. however, I believe I can transform the values to meters. Above the equator, one degree is about 111,140 meters. I just do not know how to transform the values for my area which is between about 50N to 60N.

Comment: Yeah, and at 60 ° latitude its about 38 km. A reliable transformation is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look agian at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WGS84 (EPSG 4326) is a geographic coordinate system with Lat/long coordinates in degree.

if you are not at the equator (and even if you are, but then the difference can be neglected in most applications), then 1 degree of latitude does not represent the same distance on the surface of the Earth than 1 degree of longitude. In your case, for instance around 60 degree N, one unit of your map (degree) towards the N will be TWICE as long as 1 unit of distance towards the East or West.

Therefore, it is not reliable to use [r.grow.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.grow.distance.html) with euclidian distance when you are in lat/long. One option is to project your data first (as suggested in the comments), but note that r.grow.distance has an option to build GEODESIC distance (which will be correct , and can be expressed in meters with the "-m" flag). The computation time will be longer, but it will actually be more accurate than an euclidian distance with most projected coordinate systems (because even equidistant projected coordinate systems distort the distances in some places).

Comment: that is great!! thank you for the suggestion  @radouxju!